# nftables: flush/delete when changing or creating new table

Tags: nftables

I have created a net-filter table. I have it in a script. I can not get this script to always load. If I flush/delete the table, then it does not work, if the table does not exist. If I do not flush/delete then it merges the old and new rules.

How do I flush/delete if the table exists?

```
#!/usr/sbin/nft -f

flush table my_table

table ip my_table {
    chain output {
        type filter hook output priority 0; policy accept;
        ip daddr 8.8.8.8 counter 
        ip daddr 1.1.1.1 counter
        skuid "other" jump restrict_chain
        skuid "d" jump d_chain
    }

    chain accept_chain {
        nftrace set 1 counter accept
    }

    chain reject_chain {
        nftrace set 1 counter reject
    }

    chain restrict_chain {
        #type filter priority 0; policy drop;
        counter
        ip daddr 1.1.1.1 counter
        oifname "lo" jump accept_chain
        oifname != "lo" jump reject_chain
    }

    chain d_chain {
        counter
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First declare an empty table. If the table already existed, it doesn't throw an error nor alter its content: nothing happens. If it didn't exist, the empty table was just created. Now that it exists in all cases, it can be deleted. All this can be done in *the same* ruleset.

So, declare the table without chain nor rules, then delete it (the [man page](https://manpages.debian.org/nftables/nft.8#TABLES) tells that flushing it will flush chains and rules, but this will not remove the chains themselves, they'll just be emptied, which will leave old renamed chains or sets in place or clash with them if their properties were changed. The [nftables wiki has more informations about delete and flush](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Configuring_tables#Deleting_tables) behaviours.). Now you can really create it, still in *the same and unique* ruleset file. The same ruleset can now idempotently be loaded multiple times without throwing an error even the first time.

```
#!/usr/sbin/nft -f

table ip my_table
delete table ip my_table

table ip my_table {
    chain output {
        type filter hook output priority 0; policy accept;
        ip daddr 8.8.8.8 counter 
# [...]
    }
}
```

You could choose to use an [`include`](https://manpages.debian.org/nftables/nft.8#INCLUDE_FILES) statement to put all such preparatory lines in a separate file in case there are many and you don't want them to pollute the ruleset.

You can do the same at the chain level, ie without altering other chains in the same table, nor supposing or requiring the table and its chains were here before. Here's an example to have `reject_chain` deactivate *nftrace*, which won't remove other tables nor `my_table`'s chains. The example has no real usefulness, it's just to give an example.

```
#!/usr/sbin/nft -f

table ip my_table {
    chain reject_chain {
    }
}
delete chain ip my_table reject_chain

table ip my_table {
    chain reject_chain {
        nftrace set 0 counter reject
    }
}
```

---

Compatibility note: kernels < 3.18 would require both flush + delete to work properly, as [explained](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Configuring_tables#Deleting_tables) in the wiki. This (and the equivalent for chains) would even work on any kernel version:

```
table ip my_table
flush table ip my_table
delete table ip my_table
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. Unfortunately what you describe would make it non-atomic.

Comment: Ok but non atomic to what? Since the first rule won't alter anything, there's no atomicity issue (that's why I first wrote about atomicity then deleted it). The first table creation just need to be run once at boot so there's an empty table present. Then you can forget about it.

Comment: Oh. Yes. I will try it next time, I have to edit a table.

Comment: Oops. rolled back to your version.

Comment: Mhh for compatibility reasons, I could mention that kernel < 3.18 would require both: flush + delete

Comment: So this works for tables and chains. Any idea how this could work for set/map elements? Because if I add an element that is already present, I get "Device or resource busy", but if I remove an element that isn't there, I get "No such file or directory"

Comment: @jplitza you could try to flush the set/map first. Does it work then? If still not, you should ask a separate question with a reproducer.